# using a fast drive as an emulated cache for a slow drive

Tags: networking, cache, cloud, webdav, drive

Hello I have a huge network drive from the cloud  (webdav drive mount as a local directory) which is quite slow, I would like to use a fast local drive as a cache for the slow drive and the whole thing mount transparently as a unique drive or webdav. Is there any software (preferably linux based) solution that allow this ?

A related problem is the following : I have an archive slow drive for which 99% data is not accessed very often, but the other part of the data could accessed very often. As I cannot predict which part will be needed I would like a system that would put the most recent accessed data on a fast drive available for further demand. What is the best way to solve this kind of problem ?

I heard about http://bcachefs.org/ and older bcache https://lwn.net/Articles/458417/ which looks great but I don't think it can work with a network or webdav drive

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use [dm-cache](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/device-mapper/cache.txt)?

Comment: Looks interesting but it seems to work at the block level, therefore it should not work with a webdav even if it is  mount as a directory, what do you think ?

Comment: That depends on how you mount it, I suppose. davfs is FUSE based which might work.

Comment: Interesting, I will give it a try did you notice a sizeable improvement with dm-cache ?